# Can a live tile style be created in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-metro, mahapps.metro

I'm exploring MahApps framework and I want to implement a live tile style.

My question is:

Is it possible to create a live tile **style**, where the tile's content (predefined images, texts; not content added dynamically) should change periodically and with an animation (MahApps transition)? If so, how can it be done?

I think this behavior could be achieved in code, but I'm wondering if it can be done only in xaml, in a style. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, but it's a hell of a work. I've done it onces before a couple of years ago. I've used this as my guide for it: http://www.sourceblog.mc-auto.info/post/2011/11/23/Live-Icons-in-WPF.aspx

Another take on it would be to get the WP7 silverlight toolkit http://phone.codeplex.com/ and take a look at the HubTile and convert it to your needs.